# "i/o error 6" message when i click 'cancel' in opendialog delphi 11.3

Tags: delphi, io, runtime-error

I get an "i/o error 6" message when I click 'Cancel' in an `OpenDialog` (I'm using Delphi 11.3 CE).
Why does it happen and how do I fix it?

Here is a code example, it happens when `TForm1.Button3Click()` is running. The rest of the function works properly - file opens, text from file displays.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if state=false then begin      \\examine if its need to save something before opening
    if statef=false then begin
      SaveDialog1.Execute();  \\examine if its new file and save
      FileName:=savedialog1.FileName;
      AssignFile(opfile, FileName);
      rewrite(opfile);
      texty:=Memo1.Text;
      write(opfile, texty);
      closefile(opfile);
      state:=true;
    end
    else if statef=true then begin
      statef:=true; \\examine if its opened file and save
      AssignFile(opfile, FileName);
      rewrite(opfile);
      texty:=Memo1.Text;
      write(opfile, texty);
      closefile(opfile);
      state:=true;
    end;
  end;
  Memo1.Text:='';        \\clearing field
  opendialog1.Execute();      \\opening file
  FileName:=opendialog1.FileName;
  AssignFile(opfile, FileName);
  Reset(opfile);
  while not Eof(opfile) do
  begin
    Readln(opfile, texty);
    memo1.Lines.Add(texty);      \\displaying text
  end;
  CloseFile(opfile);
  state:=true;          \\ return no saving needed
  statef:=true;          \\return file is opened already
end;
```

Comment: Why aren't you using your debugger? And why are you using legacy file IO. You should stop doing that. It's 2024.

Comment: This is not your actual code. It contains syntax errors that would prevent it from compiling, which means it cannot run to produce the error you claim it does. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue, instead of some made up code.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems within your code I'd like to address:

1. The `Execute`-Method of the `Open/SaveDialog` is a function returning a boolean value indicating success (a filename was selected or entered) or abortion of the dialog. You don't check for this result at all and just move on in your code! To solve this you need to add another if-block to your code like the following:

   ```
    if OpenDialog.Exeute then
    begin
      // here all the stuff about handling the selected file
    end;
   ```
2. Please indent your code more properly, it will increase the readability drastically! To do so you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to invoke auto code formatting!
3. Also don't check for `if something = true` / `false`, just `if x then` or `if not x then` is enough.
4. Clearing a `TMemo` can be done with `MyMemo.Clear`
5. This manual writing to and reading from a file isn't necessary at all here. You can simply do

   ```
    if SaveDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      MyMemo.Strings.SaveToFile(SaveDialog1.FileName);
    end;
   ```

   or

   ```
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      MyMemo.Strings.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
    end;
   ```

   instead!

Comment: 6.) A comment must begin with slashes `//`, not backslashes \\ - the syntax highlighting signals this already.